# How can I add table of contents, list of figures and tables in LYX file in order to get in PDF file

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I add table of contents, list of figures and tables in LYX file in order to be shown in PDF file of my thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lists are found under Insert --> List/TOC. Note that only numbered chapters/sections/subsections are by default added to the toc.